# I want to write the string in another line and with space so what should I do

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
string wsName = worksheet.Name;

int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows; 
int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;

string colError = CensusHelper.ValidateHeaderColumns(worksheet, colCount);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(colError)){
response.preliminaryError = "The census file you are attempting to upload is incorrectly formatted. Either the FuturePlan template was not"
return StatusCode(480, new ErrorDTO (ErrorMessage = response.preliminaryError });

else if (!wsName.ToLower().Contains("ver01") && !wsName.ToLower().Contains("ver@2")) { premilinaryValidationErrors.Append("Uploaded excel sheet name doesn't match. Please download latest template from Download Template link,"

} else if (rowCount <= 2 && wsName.ToLower().Contains("ver82")) { premilinaryValidationErrors.Append("There are no employees in the census file you are attempting to upload. \r\n Please verify you are upl")

}else if (rowCount <= 1 && wsName.ToLower().Contains("ver81")) { presilinaryValidationErrors.Append("There are no employees in the census file you are attempting to upload. \r\n Please verify you are upl")}
```

How can i insert a new Line in string in place of `\r\n`  in the above code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format it properly. Hint: To format a part as code, use the "{}" button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Environment.NewLine`. Like

```
    string str = "There are no employees in the census file you are attempting to upload." +  Environment.NewLine + "Please verify you are upl";
    presilinaryValidationErrors.Append(str);
```